# conditional probability with exponential random variables

Tags: probability

Radio works with two independent batteries. Each one has exponentially distributed lifetimes with mean $1/\lambda_1$ and $1/\lambda_2$ (years). Radio fails to operate as soon as one of the batteries dies.

1- what is the probability that the radio fails to operate in two years?

2- what is the probability that the radio failed to operate due to the battery one given that it has failed in two years?

I just wanted to ask if I formulate these questions correctly?

Let $X_i \sim Exp(\lambda_i)$ so that $E(X_i)=\frac{1}{\lambda_i}$.

Then

1. question is that find $P(\min(X_1,X_2)<2)$.
2. question is that find $P(X_1<X_2 | \min(X_1,X_2)<2)$. And this is equal to $\frac{P(X_1<\min(X_2,2))}{P(\min(X_1,X_2)<2)}$

is my formulation correct?

Comment: I think it is correct.

Comment: Thanks, GReyes.

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to calculate the first:

If the radio fails when at least one of the batteries dies, then we are looking for $P(X_1 < 2 \text{ or } X_2 < 2)$ for the first question. To fail in two years, one of the batteries (or both) have to had lived for less than two years.

This is equivalent to $P(X_1 < 2) + P(X_2 < 2) - P(X_1<2)P(X_2 < 2)$
as the batteries operate independently.

Then for the second, you can find $P(X_1 < X_2 \mid X_1 < 2 \text{ or } X_2 < 2)$

Comment: Thanks, WaveX. Then  $P(X_1 < X_2 \mid X_1 < 2 \text{ or } X_2 < 2)=\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}$. Correct?